# How can I prevent drivers from binding USB devices on a certain bus?

Tags: kernel, drivers, usb

I have a setup with two Logitech Unifying receivers, each receiver has a keyboard bound to it. One of the receiver is to be used by the physical machine to which the devices are connected, the other one has to be passed to a QEMU virtual machine.

I am able to manually unbind one receiver following the instructions in [How to use Linux kernel driver bind/unbind interface for USB-HID devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12005/8250). This method has some disadvantages:

- I have to determine the device identifier manually by looking at dmesg.
- Each time the virtual machine is closed, and on every reboot, the unbinding process has to be repeated.

I then tried to find kernel module options that prevents the USB driver from binding it at all and found the [`quirks` option for `usbhid`](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4581/). Unfortunately, this parameter cannot be used since I have two identical receivers with the same vendor and device ID.

The two devices are distinguishable by their separate buses. That is, `lsusb` looks like:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

Is there a way to prevent `hid-logitech-dj` (or `usbhid`) from binding a USB device on a certain bus?

The target machine is running Arch Linux 64-bit with a Linux 3.9 kernel.

Comment: Interestingly, QEMU takes over the USB device without me having to do anything. For example, pressing Alt+Tab has only effect in QEMU, it is not registered by the host anymore. I do not know whether this is guaranteed behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

Within UDEV it is possible to add a rule to search for the specific bus and set the OPTIONS to "ignore_device". Did you mention your Kernel version or OS?

Comment: `ignore_device` was removed a while back, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all have a look at [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622093/55904) - you should have all the info needed to understand how usb devices are connected.

You can then connect your device while running `udevadm monitor` to see what events are being triggered, and `udevadm test --action=<action> <path>` to see what actions *udev* is taking.

The system rules should be in `/lib/udev/rules.d` - you most likely want to override them in the `/etc/udev/rules.d` path so they don't get overridden by package upgrades. You have two choices:

1. Copy the rule from `/lib/udev/rules.d` to the same path/name in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and edit it - this is easiest as you can just alter slightly the matching filters to exclude your device/bus combination. Udev will not run any system rule for which there is a matching etc rule. Otoh any udev maintainer's change will have to me manually added.
2. Create a subsequent rule (with a *higher* priority so it runs after) and override the actions taken by earlier rules (such has removing or changing `RUN` actions).

If you have no existing rule to override, you can just add a rule to do the extra work needed such as running the unbind/bind commands.

To find appropriate rule filters, you can use `usevadm info <path>` to see device properties. With the `-a` switch you will instead get all *sysfs* attributes for the device *and all its parent nodes*, which can all be used for matching as well (for attributes duplicates, the first match is used).

See `man udev` (7) for detailed instructions on writing rules.