# How to disable a device (hardware) from using hid-multitouch driver?

Tags: modprobe, hid

I have a Kortek touch screen that is exposed to the system, as shown in `/proc/bus/input/devices`, via two drivers :
`hid-generic` and `hid-multitouch`

I do not want `hid-multitouch` driver to expose Kortek touchscreen meaning I want to disable Kortek from hid-multitouch.

Is there a way I can do this ?
can I use quirks ? and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running your kernel, you could [unbind the driver from the device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/how-to-use-linux-kernel-driver-bind-unbind-interface-for-usb-hid-devices), or you could remove your device from the `mt_devices` `id_table` inside `drivers/hid/hid-multitouch.c` in the linux kernel source.